# How to convert .doc into textures?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm using Blender 2.8 and Eevee. I need to read many super long text documents (.doc), some being as much as 500 pages, and to convert them into images to be textured on plane meshes that will be very slowly flipped as book pages. The format of some of those .doc is Letter US (215.9 by 279.4 mm), others are Legal US (216 x 356 mm). Is there a simple way to read a .doc and convert each of its pages into a very good quality image, so that when used as a texture and rendered in Blender, it could be zoomed in and read super easily ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender

Comment: You could probably do it easily with a virtual printer set to an image file format. On a side note you will probably encounter memory problems rendering scenes with more than a few hundred different image textures.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks a lot!  From your 2nd answer, I was able to convert (as a test) a 10 pages .doc to .png and .jpg images using Microsoft XPS Document Writer followed by STDUViewerApp.